# Where can one find a list of operator overloads?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

Where can one find a list of the function signatures for all operator overloads?

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 14):

Wikipedia: [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

Answer (score 8):

ISO/IEC 14882:2003 §13.5, Overloaded Operators

It's not quite as useful as the Wikipedia list if you don't have a copy of the document, but it has the benefit of being authoritative.

You can also consult the latest draft of C++0x, [N3126](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3126.pdf), §13.5, Overloaded Operators.

Comment: I am not sure how I got to it, and did not bookmark as I have my own copy, but the current standard is (was) available in a link through google code somewhere. You should be able to *google* for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can find them on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com), divided by operator cagetory:

- [Assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment): `a=b`, `a+=b`, `a-=b`, `a*=b`, `a/=b`, `a%=b`, `a&=b`, `a|=b`, `a^=b`, `a<<=b`, `a>>=b`
- [Increment and decrement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec): `++a`, `--a`, `a++`, `a--`
- [Arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic): `+a`, `-a`, `a+b`, `a-b`, `a*b`, `a/b`, `a%b`, `~a`, `a&b`, `a|b`, `a^b`, `a<<b`, `a>>b`
- [Logical operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical): `a||b`, `a&&b`, `!a`
- [Comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison): `a==b`, `a!=b`, `a<b`, `a>b`, `a<=b`, `a>=b`, `a<=>b`(C++20)
- [Member access operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access): `a[b]`, `*a`, `&a`, `a->b`, `a.b`, `a->*b`, `a.*b`
- [Other operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other): `a(...)`, `a,b`, `a?b:c`

I suggest to check the *Canonical implementations* in the [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) page.

Answer (score 0):

In the book: "Thinking in C++, 2nd ed. Volume 1" by Bruce Eckel

You can read it online. The chapter you are looking for (chapter 12), can be found [here](http://www.briceg.com/eckel/one/), for example.

Comment: Hmm, I went straight for the `operator->*` description (as that's the most likely place for errors) and sure enough he claims it can only be used to return functors, i.e. emulate pointer to member functions, not pointers to data members. For what it's worth… also, link to chapter: http://www.briceg.com/eckel/one/Chapter12.html